# ¿Cuando importamos Pandas estamos importando Numpy automaticamente?

Tags: pandas, numpy

Vi que dentro del codigo fuente de pandas esta la instruccion import numpy as np; entonces cuando importamos Pandas automaticamente tambien se importa numpy?

Alguien me lo explica porfavor, porque mi profesor importa siempre las dos librerias al inicio cuando codifica, pero me pregunto siempre lo de arriba.

El codigo fuente lo saque de aqui:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/frame.py

Comment: Nop, pandas importa numpy porque su código lo necesita y pertenecerá al script que lo importe, no se importa globalmente. Si tu quieres hacer uso de numpy deberás importarlo o acceder a la variable (por ejemplo `np`) definida en algún script de pandas

Comment: Pero aqui https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/frame.py pareceria que esta importando Numpy globalmente, puedes explicar esa parte mejor porfa?

Comment: Nop, yo solo veo que hizo `import numpy as np` lo que quiere decir que lo esta importando para su archivo, si quieres puedes realizar la pruebas. Después de haber hecho `import pandas as pd` trata de hacer `np.array` o `numpy.array` o `pd.array` o cualquier cosa que se te ocurra y verás un bonito error :D